# Azure CDN purge command issue

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cli

I have created a CDN named 'cdn-profile', in resource group 'rgDev' . In the CDN the endpoint created is 'webqa.azureedge.net'. Inside that I have created a custom domain 'qa.example.com'.  I wanted to purge the CDN cache. Below is the command I run.

```js
$ResourceGroupName='rgDev'
$EndpointName='qa.example.com'
$ProfileName='cdn-profile'
$CDNEndPointName='webqa.azureedge.net'

 az cdn endpoint purge -g $ResourceGroupName -n $EndpointName --profile-name $ProfileName --content-paths '/*' --name $CDNEndPointName
```

This gives me below error:
Endpoint(s) not found. Please verify the resource(s), group or it's parent resources exist.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Azure CLI command [az cdn endpoint purge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cdn/endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest#az_cdn_endpoint_purge), the name of the CDN endpoint is `webqa`(It is the name of the resource that type is Endpoint in your resource group.) instead of the hostname `webqa.azureedge.net` or `qa.example.com`.

You should use it like this:

```
$ResourceGroupName='rgDev'
$ProfileName='cdn-profile'
$CDNEndPointName='webqa'

 az cdn endpoint purge -g $ResourceGroupName  --profile-name $ProfileName --content-paths '/*' --name $CDNEndPointName
```

Comment: Hi Nancy, I updated the same but its giving same error.

Comment: Do you use the same command？I found you define two -n    and - -name or reopen your shell？

Comment: Ah I see, yes, I used it twice. Let me update you after running the updated command

Comment: Thank you @Nancy , I am able to fix that issue now.